# Proving that simple-connectedness of domains is preserved under analytic maps with analytic inverse?

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness, analytic-functions

Let $A,B$ be domains in $\mathbb{C}$, with $A$ simply-connected, and $f:A\rightarrow B$ be analytic and invertible, with analytic inverse. I need to prove that $B$ is also simply-connected.

I have tried proof by contradiction:

Suppose that $B$ is not simply-connected. Then there exists a cycle $\gamma$ in $B$ and $a\in\mathbb{C}\setminus B$ with $n(\gamma,a)\neq0$.

$f^{-1}\circ\gamma$ is a cycle in $A$ and $A$ is simply-connected, so $n(f^{-1}\circ\gamma,w)=0$ $\forall w\in \mathbb{C} \setminus A$.

Then by the general form of Cauchy's Theorem, we have that $\int_{f^{-1}\circ\gamma} f=0$.

Not sure if I'm heading in the right direction. Any hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many characterizations of simply connectedness. One of them says that a region is simply connected iff every analytic function on it  wit o zeros has an analytic logarithm primitive. Now let $g$ be analytic in $B$ and suppose $g$ has no zeros. Then $g\circ f$ is analytic in $A$ and it has no zeros. So $g(f(z))=e^{h(z)}$ for  some analytic function $h$ on $A$. Since $h\circ f^{-1}$ is analytic on $B$ and $e^{(h\circ f^{-1})(z)}=g(z)$ we are done.

Comment: The definition of simple-connectedness that I have been given in lectures is that a domain $D$ is simply-connected if for any closed piecewise smooth contour $\gamma$ in $D$ and any $a$ not in $D$, the winding number is zero.